# 'QObject::QObject' cannot access private member declared in class 'QObject'

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, qt4

```
class CHIProjectData : public QObject
{
public:
    CHIProjectData();
    CHIProjectData(QMap<QString,QString> aProjectData,
                   CHIAkmMetaData* apAkmMetaData = 0,
                   QObject* parent = 0);
private:
    QMap <QString,QString> m_strProjectData;
    CHIAkmMetaData* m_pAkmMetaData;
};

CHIProjectData::CHIProjectData(QMap<QString,QString> aProjectData,
                               CHIAkmMetaData* apAkmMetaData,
                               QObject* aParent)
    :
    QObject(aParent)
{
        m_strProjectData = aProjectData;
        m_pAkmMetaData = apAkmMetaData;
}
```

Why does it give the "'QObject::QObject' cannot access private member declared in class 'QObject'" error?

Comment: What causes the error? What line triggers it?

Comment: And why not use the initializer list to initialize all the members?

Comment: @Charles: the error points to the last line of CHIProjectData class declaration.

Comment: @Charles: adding QObject as the base class triggers the error. Earlier without base class the program was working fine

Comment: @Arun: That doesn't seem right. The error should only be triggered if something causes the default constructor to be used. Where's your definition of your default constructor?

Comment: Yeah, the default ctor impl would be interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a copy constructor to CHIProjectData class did the trick.

Comment: Just be aware that you're not truly copying the entirety of CHIProjectData, unless you are doing a bunch more work in the copy constructor to copy settings from the original instance's QObject parent to the new instance's QObject parent.  This includes things like signal and slot connections.

Answer (score 30):

I'm guessing that your `CHIProjectData` class is being copied somewhere (using the compiler-generated copy constructor or assignment operator).  `QObject` cannot be copied or assigned to, so that would cause an error.  However, the compiler has no line to point to for the error, so it chooses some line in the file (the final brace is common, since that is when the compiler knows if it should generate those functions or not, after parsing the class declaration to see if they already exist).

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly my problem, although the line copying the QObject was in another code file. (And it was hidden in a `myObject = MyObjectClass()`, too.)

Answer (score 13):

The default constructor for `QObject` must be private and the error you are getting is quite likely to do with `CHIProjectData::CHIProjectData` (default constructor) implicitly trying to invoke base class's default constructor. If you look at `QObject` you would most likely find that it's defined something like this:

```
class QObject {
    QObject(); //private contructor, derived classes cannot call this constructor
public:
    QObject(QObject* aParent);
};
```

The solution is to make default `QObject` constructor protected or public or call other constructor overload from the default `CHIProjectData` constructor:

```
CHIProjectData::CHIProjectData() : QObject(NULL){
}
```

Comment: Or have `aProjectData` default to `QMap<QString,QString>()`, so you get a default constructor for free.

Comment: Good theory, but the only constructor for `QObject` is public, `QObject(QObject* parent=0)`. And changing Qt's API isn't really an option.

Answer (score 3):

When using `QObject` subclass objects try to manipulate with pointers.

take the problematic scenario

```
myObject = MyObjectClass()
```

in this case  its more clean to have

```
MyObjectClass *myObject;
//code
myObject = new MyObjectClass;
```

This would remove the need for object copying and assignments by using reference copying and  assignments.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that the  `Q_OBJECT` macro silently introduces a `private:` specifier, even within a struct:

```
struct myClass : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   // everything here is private now...
}
```